# Can I stream from Safari silverlight to AppleTV?

Tags: safari, appletv, streaming, silverlight

I'm using Sky Sports Now TV to watch live sport on my Mac. This is via the silverlight plugin in Safari. Can I use something to divert this video feed to my Apple TV so I can watch on my television without using a cable?

I should clarify, I need a solution right now since I want to watch the Heineken Cup rugby final starting now and I have a 2009 MacBook Pro so I can't use AirPlay.

Comment: Thunderbolt to HDMI cable :) it cost about $8.

Comment: Thanks but I should clarify, I want to do it right now for the Heineken Cup rugby final. So I don't have the cable.

Comment: outch............ what cables do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [AirParrot](http://airparrot.com/). Depending on your connection speed, it may be adequate for what you're trying to do. The company also offers a free trial.

Comment: This works reasonably well

Comment: Glad to hear it. If I remember correctly, I think the trial quits after a certain amount of time. You might have to buy a license to avoid having to set it up over and over.

Comment: Yup it's 20 minutes

Comment: Please also note that in the latest version of AirParrot (1.5.3) this will only work with Apple TV 2. AirParrot will not work with Apple TV 1 (with the HD).

Answer (score 2):

AirPlay can mirror the display of your mac to the AppleTV. This only works with 2011 model macs and newer running Mac OS X 10.8

more details:
http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5404

Comment: saw your edits, guess this won't be the best solution for you.

Comment: It was a good suggestion though for others with a more modern Mac so I upvoted anyway.  From what I've read on Sky's forums, their developers have specifically disabled airplay. I haven't tried this myself though.

Answer (score 1):

Normal one would do that with Thunderbolt to HDMI cable.

In you case (you do not have the cable but want to watch the game right now).

Get an Ethernet cable (every household has one).

.....hardwired the MBP and Apple TV with a standard Ethernet cable.

Then enabled Systems Preferences/Sharing/Internet, then indicated "From" as Airport and "To be shared with" as Ethernet.

Then turned on Airparrot and mirror you screen with with ease.

To go back to WiFi Apple TV, unplug.

Comment: How do you mirror the screen though as you've suggested?